# startActivityForResult showing data on previous data every time sending new data

Tags: android

I have two activities. Main activity and child activity. When I press a button, the child activity is launched from here. I want to send some data back to the main screen. I used startActivityForResult but is working but each time when i collect data it shows data on previous data(i.e previous data didn"t get cleared when I again sending new data..it forms like stack)? How to clear previous data each time while sending new data.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_image);

    ivLauncher = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_launcher);
    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class), 1002);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1002) {
        String duty = data.getStringExtra("WHICH");
        if (duty.equalsIgnoreCase("flag")) {

            ivLauncher.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_assistant);

        } else if (duty.equalsIgnoreCase("music")) {
            ivLauncher.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_audiotrack);

        } else if (duty.equalsIgnoreCase("moon")) {
            ivLauncher.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_brightness);

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

SecondActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    rlMoon = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_moon);
    rlMoon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("WHICH", "moon");
            setResult(1002, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
    rlMusic = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_music);
    rlMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("WHICH", "music");
            setResult(1002, i);
            finish();

        }
    });
    rlFlag = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_flag);
    rlFlag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("WHICH", "flag");
            setResult(1002, i);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post how you did that

Comment: If you want to pass simple data use Bundle and put it inside the Intent and then fetch it.

Comment: welcome to SO! please edit your question with code you done to achieve this so others can easily help you! thank you.

Comment: It is showing selected image on ivLauncher but in background showing launcher image i put on this relative layout so i want to clear that dafault image when select any other image

Answer (score 2):

you can also send data like this..

in child activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
String data = mEditText.getText();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("Data", data);
setResult(resultcode, intent);
}
```

in main activity

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String myStr=data.getStringExtra("Data");
        mTextView.setText(myStr);
    }
}
}
```